# Black Eyed Susan Question

Tags: plant-health, flowers, outdoor

I planted some Black-Eyed Susan's on a grave site here in Coastal North Carolina a week-and-a-half ago.

I watered them well a few times over the past week-and-half the last time being last Saturday (a week ago) but when I went to check on them today I was upset to find them shriveled and looking like they were dying.

I did my best to try to see if I could revive them by watering them and will go and check on them again tomorrow, but I was originally told that these were kind of drought resistant.  Perhaps they needed to be better established and watered more frequently before expecting drought tolerance.

I was hoping that perhaps I can save these by watering more frequently that since they are perennials perhaps they may become more established and return next summer.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they have to be well established before you can leave them a week in the summer without water. The plant needs to grow roots down to a level with some humidity. Until then it is dependent on watering or rain.

Assuming you are in Wilmington NC, US, I just checked the weather: **Hot summer!**

Under such conditions I would water the new plants at least every second day.

Comment: Thanks. Generally speaking, how long does it take this particular variety to become established?  Also, I should still be able to save the plant if I continue to water as directed?

Comment: Mid-summer is generally a bad time for transplanting. One would normally transplant BES in fall or spring, when they would have an easier time establishing. Whether or not the plant recovers after having been severely wilted is impossible to say, other than by trying it and see what happens. I killed a tomato but the marigold with it was OK, and after a week or two the dead tomato sprouted new foliage, so it wasn't quite that dead.

Comment: @Tikhon It is more a matter of how deep roots the plant needs to develop to reach humidity in the soil. If you are using a fertilizer then make sure to select one high in K/potassium. This will speed up the process. On the other hand fertilizers tend to increase the need for frequent watering. When watering make sure to supply water until the soil are wet several inches below the surface. If only the top inch is wet, then you stimulates root development in this layer only. Humidity from deeper layers evaporates slowly, and soon you can increase the watering interval. I think they will survive.

Comment: Thank you all!
God Bless..